# Need to generate a dictionary using comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have this code in python:

```
    layers = ['two', 'three', 'five', 'six']
    dict_toggle_bullet = {}
    for x, y in enumerate(layers):
       dict_toggle_bullet[y] = ["active" if j == y else "" for _, j in enumerate(layers)]
```

The output is:

```
{'two': ['active', '', '', ''], 'three': ['', 'active', '', ''], 'five': ['', '', 'active', ''], 'six': ['', '', '', 'active']}
```

Is there a way to convert this using dictionary comprehension in a single line?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
lst = ['two','three','five','six']
d = {lst[i]:['' if j != i else 'active' for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)}
```

However, I wouldn't advice you to do this as it seems a bit complicated and difficult to understand, so the direct method  looks to be better.

Comment: Thanks Prats. As per your suggestion will go with the direct method